# Indicator matrix for non-exclusive factors

Tags: r

Say I have a list containing vectors of factors:

```
colors <- c("red", "green", "blue")
f <- factor(colors, levels=colors)
rgb <- sapply(sample(1:3, 5, replace=TRUE), function(n) sample(f, n))
```

Which might look like this:

```
> invisible(sapply(rgb, function(x) print(x, max.levels=0)))
[1] blue  green
[1] red
[1] blue  red   green
[1] red   blue  green
[1] blue
```

How can I construct a matrix of indicator values that represent the same information:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1
[5,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: While my question may be similar to the one linked, I believe @akrun's solves my problem significantly more simply than any of the answers in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
t(sapply(rgb, table))
```